# Batch File to Loop Over Files In a Folder and Run Exe for Info

Tags: windows, batch-file, forfiles

I am writing a *.BAT file to count the frames in every GIF file in a folder. Writing all that to TXT files would be nice, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

I can do this from the command line for single files.

This does what I want, but it does not output the number of frames to the window.
The next line is a sample of what it should do for a single file.

```
"c:\program files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8\identify.exe" -format %%n 14215349.gif
```

These two lines should do the same for every file in the folder.
But, they just echo the command, rather than show its output.

```
set "frames=^0x22c:\program^ files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8\identify.exe^0x22^ -format^ %%n"
forfiles /m *.gif /c "cmd /c echo %frames% @file"
```

The only thing I can see wrong is the double quotes, but this shows that's not it:

```
"c:\program files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8\identify.exe" -format %%n "14215349.gif"
pause
```

It should output an integer for each file. Line 1 does this. Lines 2 and 3 do not; they just `echo` the command.

Comment: Have you considered removing `echo` from the forfiles command? `:)`

Comment: Don't use `forfiles` for this task. Use command `for`. Open a cmd window and run `for /?` for help. I don't have *Image Magick* installed and so don't know what is output, but something like `for %%I in (*.gif) do "%ProgramFiles%\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8\identify.exe" -format %%n "%%I" >>FramesList.txt` should be helpful for you to start.

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
for %%I in (*.gif) do "c:\program files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8\identify.exe" -format %%n %%I >>FramesList.txt
pause
```

Thanks.

I hope I can ask for one more thing. The output I get is integers only, on one line, no spaces of filenames. How do I write this so the FramesList.txt file shows the frame count integer (never more than 3 digits) followed by the filename on each line?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%K In (*.gif)Do If /I "%%~xK"==".gif" (
    "%ProgramFiles%\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8\identify.exe" -format "%%[n] %%[f]" "%%K"
)>>"FramesList.txt"
```

In the example above, I have used `%%K` for safety, because there are no short form attributes which use `%K` and it is a distinct character, *for recognition purposes*. In addition, I have decided to use the long form attributes percent escapes for the number of images, and filename, i.e. `%[n]` and `%[f]`, for the same reason, *because, from a batch file, `%%n` and `%%f` could be confused with `For` metavariables*.

The `If` statement was included because `*.gif` does not loop through files with `.gif` extensions, it loops all extensions which begin with `.gif`. *Whilst you may not have any which match this scenario, there's no real reason not to add in the additional safety*.

Comment: Very odd behavior (I script, but not in this language much, so I know what it's doing, but I don't get how to fix it). It is writing 1) the number of frames for the first file, 2) then the filename repeated that number of times (it would be nice if that was just once), then NOT repeating this for the next file: it only does (2) for every following file (maybe it needs a linefeed in there somewhere too).